# If we have $f : x→ y$ with $S \subset x$ what can we say about $f^{-1}f(S)$ and $S$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, solution-verification

Here is the full question:

> Let $f : X → Y$ be a function from one set $X$ to another set $Y$, let $S$ be a subset of $X$, and let $U$ be a subset of $Y$. What, in general, can one say about $f^{−1}(f(S))$ and $S$? What about $f(f^{−1}(U))$ and $U$?

My reasoning:

-$f^{−1}(f(S))=S$ if and only if $f(S)$ is a one-to-one function since no two different inputs will map to one output, so we will always get our original input when we reverse the process.

-$f(f^{−1}(U))=U$ if and only if $f(U)$ is a bijective function, this way we can guarantee and there is an input to "go back to" when we reverse the process AND we will go back to the correct input (since it's unique).

Why I posted this: I feel like I am missing something in the question, I am new to analysis and always pretty unsure about my reasoning especially that there is no solutions available for this, I want to make sure about building on the correct blocks of understanding. If someone can help me point out my mistakes if there is any or suggest improvements about the way of writing proofs (I guess I use too much English) I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $S$ and $U$ are fixed, your statements are actually false.  That is, the following are true:

- $f^{-1}(f(S)) = S$ for all $S \subseteq X$ if and only if $f$ is injective.
- $f(f^{-1}(U)) = U$ for all $U \subseteq Y$ if and only if $f$ is surjective.

However, since $S$ and $U$ are fixed in the problem statement, we could have $f^{-1}(f(S)) = S$ without $f$ being injective, and we could have $f(f^{-1}(U))=U$ without $f$ being surjective.

---

Instead, this type of question, usually, is asking you to verify which of the following are necessarily true:

- $f^{-1}(f(S)) \subseteq S$
- $f^{-1}(f(S)) \supseteq S$
- $f(f^{-1}(U)) \subseteq U$
- $f(f^{-1}(U)) \supseteq U$

---

As a final note, for a fixed $S$ and $U$ we still have the direction of

- $f^{-1}(f(S)) = S$ if $f$ is injective.
- $f(f^{-1}(U)) = U$ if $f$ is surjective.

If you want to additionally prove those, I'm sure your instructor wouldn't mind, as the question is certainly open-ended.

Comment: But where was is mentioned that $U$ and $S$ are fixed? I understand that these wouldn't be true if they were fixed but this wasn't mentioned

Comment: @Sergio "Let $f : X \to Y$ be a function from one set $X$ to another set $Y$, let $S$ be a subset of $X$, and let $U$ be a subset of $Y$" - This fixes $f$, $X$, $Y$, $S$ and $U$.

Comment: Oh, thank you. and about the other statements my a quick answer would no for the first statement (example: a function that is isn't one to one like $f(S)=S^2$ and our subset only has one of the answers), is that correct? if you could give a quick yes/no answer for all 4 just for me to verify my answers later on I would be glad, thank you.

Comment: Also the second statement is correct, regardless of the function is one to one or not $S$ will still be a subset as it will be part of the inputs that lead to this answer

Comment: third statement seems true to me, unless we can't consider $\emptyset \in S$ as worst case scenario we won't be left with anything, example $f(S)=S^2$ domain and co-domain is the natural numbers $S=\{2,3,5\}$

Comment: considering the fourth statement, false. Using the previous example if we are left with an empty set then $\forall U , U \notin \emptyset$

Comment: sorry for my second to last comment I meant $U$
 not $S$